# Alpha & beta in investing

Tags: equities

In stock analysis the baseline for alpha is 0, however for beta it's 1. Why is that so, if they are both comparisons to the market at a large?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you are working with the CAPM there. Alpha is a measure of how much excess return e.g. a stock generates, while Beta is a measure of how volatile its price is relative to the market. So the "baseline" or market does obviously have a beta of one with an Alpha of zero (no excess return since you are looking at the market/"baseline" as you called it), according to the CAPM.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Good answer. You can also think of it like this: the market excess return is MULTIPLIED by Beta and then Alpha is ADDED. To get the same result you started with you need Beta of 1 and Alpha of 0; after all 1 is the identity for Multiplication and 0 is the identity for Addition.